# Makefile that gives permission to my python script?

Tags: python, shell, makefile

I have a python script named "myprogram.py" and a shell script named "myprogram" for running this

```
# "myprogram"

#!/bin/sh
python myprogram.py
```

I created this shell script because I wanted to run my program like this:

```
./myprogram arg1 arg2
```

However, when I do this, I get this "Permission Denied" error.

I know I need to type "chmod 755 myprogram" to grant permission, but I want to do this

in my makefile instead of making the user manually type chmod.

In other words, I want my makefile so that typing

```
./make
```

runs "chmod 755 myprogram"

Is there a way to do this?? What should the content of my makefile be?

Thanks

Comment: If the only reason you're using an additional script is to run it that way, you might also want to consider adding `#! /usr/bin/env python` at the top of the `.py` file, and simply running it as `./myprogram.py` (after setting x permissions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting something like this into `Makefile`:

```
all: myprogram
    chmod 755 myprogram
```

That registers `myprogram` as a dependency to the `all` target.

Note that the second line there should start with a hard tab character, not spaces, as Makefiles are very particular about indentation.

Regarding the shell script: there's two ways to write it.

```
python myprogram.py $1 $2
```

This will pass the first two arguments to the script through to the python program.

However, if you do

```
python myprogram.py $@
```

then all arguments passed to the shell script will be propagated through to the python program.

Comment: Try running `make` instead of `./make`

Comment: Hm.. for some reason it says "*** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop."

Comment: What's the filename of the makefile? It should be `Makefile`.

Comment: Oh yeah I changed it, but now it says "missing spearator" Sorry :(

Comment: I think your problem is the indentation. That second line *has* to start with a hard tab character, not spaces.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42907/discussion-between-avp-and-user2492270)

Answer (score 1):

There is no point using Make to do this.  Make is not designed for it.  You should just issue the command `chmod 755 myprogram` yourself and bedone.  This command can be ensapsulated in a script or alias, if you like, but not in a makefile, and you can then enter `myprogram` into your favourite version control system that preserves permissions, so that if you recreate it elsewhere, the permissions are set.  Make is not the way to do it.

If you however must do it this way (because the boss says so for example), it would be incorrect to have `all` depend on `myprogram`.  `myprogram` already exists and `all` has nothing to do with changes to the contents of `myprogram` or modification time thereof.  It should be:

```
all:
    chmod 755 myprogram
```